# How to convert from unicode with python

Tags: python, unicode

In database I have saved string in which the problem word is: za\u0161\u010diten.

[ed.: the "problem word" seems to have changed]

When I want to present this string on my page (with **req.write(string)**). I get this error: **UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 686-687: ordinal not in range(128)**.

I am using Python 2.X on Windows|linux|Mac. [ed.: select one]
My string is actually named `html_h2`. Here are the details I was asked for:
[ed.: whitespace inserted for legibility]

```
>> print type(html_h2)
<type 'unicode'>
>> print repr(html_h2)
u"\n<table bgcolor='white' border=1 cellpadding=2 cellspacing=1 rules=rows frame=box>
  <tr>
    <td align='center'>
      <img src=img/_up/upload/2010/03/03/… width=120 height=100/>
    </td>
    <td align='left' style=width:86%>
      <h3>V Gr\u010diji kot v vojni</h3>
      Gr\u0161ki premier je finan\u010dne razmere v dr\u017eavi, ki je skoraj pred bankrotom, primerjal z razmerami v vojni. Napovedani so ostri var\u010devalni ukrepi.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>"
```

I insert database fields in string with %s. [ed.: irrelevant]

When I do as Ignacio suggested:

```
req.write(html_h2.encode('XXXXXX'))
```

where XXXXXX is the charset I declared in the Content-Type header, this happens:

[ed.: delete the outcome that doesn't happen]
(1) It displays just like I'd hoped for.
(2) I get an error message: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 2):

```
req.write(string.encode(encoding))
```

where `encoding` is the charset you declared in the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: Is that a statement or a question?

Comment: Question. Because your statement is not running.Some other solution.

Comment: "Is not running"... Did you put an appropriate value for `encoding`?

Answer (score 0):

If `string` refers to the `string` module, then yes that `string` doesn't have `encode`. If `string` is in fact a `unicode` object, then it does have an `encode` but perhaps `string` may in fact be an `str` object.

Back to basics: please give us some information.

Please show the results of:

```
# Python 2.X
print type(string)
print repr(string)
```

or

```
# Python 3.X
print(type(string))
print(ascii(string))
```

Then we can give you informed advice rather than uninformed guesses.

Note: please edit your question to show the output, don't respond in a comment. Use copy/paste, don't type from memory.

Comment: # Python 2.x

>> print type(html_h2)
<type 'unicode'>

>> print repr(html_h2)
u"\n<table bgcolor='white' border=1 cellpadding=2 cellspacing=1 rules=rows frame=box><tr><td align='center'><img src=http://img/_up/upload/2010/03/03/64670591_grcija-taksist_show.jpg width=120 height=100/></td><td align='left' style=width:86%><h3>V Gr\u010diji kot v vojni</h3>Gr\u0161ki premier je finan\u010dne razmere v dr\u017eavi, ki je skoraj pred bankrotom, primerjal z razmerami v vojni.  Napovedani so ostri var\u010devalni ukrepi.</td></tr></table>"

and I insert database fields in string with %s.

Comment: @Gogoo: Now do you understand what "please edit your question" means? Please take over from me and tell your full story.